# How to restrict the Android application to run only a certain time period?

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application that runs for a **certain time interval**.

*[EDITED]* **By certain time interval, I mean if a user downloads an application from the play store.** **He can review all the features and functionality for a fixed period of time let say X hours only.** After that, we can put any kind restriction (any UI/Navigation restriction so that user cannot review the features).

*[The Problem]*

what is the easiest as well as an efficient way of doing it? Like I don't think these solutions will work:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Or

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

What is the best way of putting restrictions (application side or server side as I have seen in some of the game application, where a synchronization is made between a server and application so that user cannot simply change the time and access the features).

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "runs for a certain time interval" means.

Comment: if somebody download the application from my website (that build the application dynamically for him), then i want the application to be run for let say 1 hour @CommonsWare

Comment: let say application like amazon after downloaded works and fine and after a hour it say "hello times up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want to run your application for a certain period of time in the first run you need to keep a track if its a first run. So you might take set a preference variable so that it can tell you that if its a first run or not.

Now set a `CountDownTimer` and set it to run for an hour and when the timer is finished, close the Activity by calling `finish()` to it.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ApplicationTag", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (pref.contains("FIRST_LAUNCH")){
    finish(); // As you want, it can't be used if the application launches second time.  

} else {
    // Set the first launch flag to true. 
    pref.edit.putBoolean("FIRST_LAUNCH", true).commit();

    // Start the count down timer
    new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisRemaining) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // Finish the Activity
        finish();
    }

}.start();
```

So you might thinking that what if I switch between Activities. So in that case, you make create a `BaseActivity` class which will be extended by other Activities in your application. Place the `CountDownTimer` code there and take a reference of the `Context` you're in then call `context.finish()` when the timer is finished.

So in case of you don't want to limit the user for first launch, you need to save the time somehow in your application. When the `Activity` is finished, you'll get the callback in `onDestroy` function. So override the `onDestroy` function and set some preference again with the remaining time in mili seconds. So that you can initialize the timer again when the application starts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yeah that's easy and helpful and i am adding CountDownTimer object in the Application. So that is accesible everytime.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to restrict the user for one run. that means i want to save the remaining time not the first_launch variable.
So the question is that is how to determine that application is closed either manually by user or by OS. So that i can save the remaining time.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Mark as accepted if it helps.

Comment: What if we use some kind of Service  ? @Reaz

Comment: Yes, of course, there are some other ways. I think its easier to keep track how much time spent using the application in the way mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, that was the exact simple answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an Alarm for firing any activity after any amount of time you want. Like following:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityYouWantToStart.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
calendar.add(Calendar.Hour,1);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

Call this code when user launches your code for first time and inside `ActivityYouWantToStart.class` do whatever you want to do after such amount of time.

Comment: what if the user save change the date from calendar, This might hack the application